# How to point at the templates folder of a module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do you make Drupal read the templates you create or override in a module (when you create templates that get overriden in the theme folder, Drupal reads them automatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) or [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) (in the case you are overriding a template file defined from another module), you use the "path" property to tell Drupal where the template file is.
This is particularly important with `hook_theme_registry_alter()`, since you are overriding the template file used by another module, and you want Drupal looks for the template file in your module's directory. With `hook_theme()`, it is important to use the "path" property when the template file is not in the directory containing the module (or the theme), but in another directory, for example in a sub-directory of the directory containing the module/theme.